# Accessing Local Settings in Windows 10

Tags: wpf, configuration, windows-10, tablet, application-settings

I am developing a Line-of-Business app for a client. The client specified the devices that were supposed to be used (some Dell tablet with Windows 8.1). Now, that the development is almost done and we were ready to release the first phase of the application, the client informed us that they have changed their mind and all those Dell tablets will run windows 10. I upgraded one tablet that I used for development and testing to Windows 10 as well. The tablet uses a RESTful Web API to access data stored in a repository. Obviously, the URL of the Web API must be configured in the settings of the app before the app can retrieve any data from the repository.
So I create the App Package to sideload the app on the tablet. The installation works properly, the app starts well for the first time. I go into the settings, set the URL and close the app.
When I try to restart, the app gets stuck showing the Splash Screen. If I try to access the Settings, I am informed that the settings for my app are not available at that time. The only way to get out of this is to uninstall the app and reinstall it again.

This is the code I use to save and retrieve the settings:

```
  public void SaveSetting<T>(string settingName, T value)
  {
     ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values[settingName] = value;
  }

  public T GetSetting<T>(string settingName)
  {
     var localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values;

     if (localSettings.ContainsKey(settingName))
     {
        var value = localSettings[settingName];

        if (value is T)
        {
           return (T)value;
        }
     }
     // else, in all other cases
     return default(T);
  }
```

An interesting thing I noticed is that sometimes, depending on what I try to save in the settings, the app starts. For example, I was playing with it and tried to save some garbage instead of the correct URL. So instead of "http://x.x.x.x:nnnnn" I saved "a". The app started correctly, I got past the splash screen but obviously, I couldn't get any data.

Any ideas as to what exactly is happening? Did the access method for local settings change in Windows 10?

I have been scratching my head over this for the past couple of days. Initially, I thought it is a matter of permissions to create the Local Settings file, so I dedicated a lot of energy trying to find a solution from that perspective. However, as I said, if I dump some garbage in the settings, it works, so it's not a matter of permissions. Could it be that and IP address like "x.x.x.x" needs to be saved in a different way than as a string?

Any advice would be highly appreciated.

TIA,
Eddie

Comment: After I added some logging to my application I was able to prove that the app had no issues reading the settings. It's what it tried to do with them that it did not work. The URL read from the settings was correct but when the app tried to make calls to the Web API, the calls threw an exception and the app stopped working. Can one of the managers of this forum close this question? Thanks, Eddie

Answer (score 0):

After I added some logging to my application I was able to prove that the app had no issues reading the settings. It's what it tried to do with them that it did not work. The URL read from the settings was correct but when the app tried to make calls to the Web API, the calls threw an exception and the app stopped working. So this shouldn't have been a question in the first place.
Thanks, Eddie